# Shaping input for keras model prediction

Tags: keras

I would like to predict a input image with my trained keras model. However, the model's input shape is different from sample shape. I used `channels_first` as `image_data_format` for the model. My image `(img_width, img_height) = (150, 150)`

The following is my code for reading image from path and prediction error from keras.

```
from scipy import misc

img_width, img_height = 150, 150


def get_img(img_path):
"""read image file from path
"""
    img = misc.imread(img_path)
    img_size = (img_width, img_height)
    return misc.imresize(img, img_size)


>>> model.input.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(150), Dimension(150), Dimension(3)])

>>> sample = get_img('mysample.png')
>>> sample.shape
150, 150, 3
```

You can see the model's input shape is `(None, 150, 150, 3)` which consists of `None`. Thus, I tried to reshape my sample with `None` but it does not work.

```
sample.reshape(img_height, img_width, 3, None)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The sample's `shape (img_height, img_width, 3, 1)` also does not work:

```
s = sample.reshape(img_height, img_width, 3, 1)

model.predict(s)

ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (None, 150, 150, 3) but got array with shape (150, 150, 3, 1)
```

How can I reshape my input image to fit the model input shape in this case ?

Comment: You were almost there, the correct shape is `(1,150,150,3)`, you just need to use reshape with `1` as first argument. As a bonus answer, instead of reshape, in case of numpy arrays you can use either `np.expand_dims(array, axis=0)` or  `array = array[None, :]` to add a dimension